# Speaker wall plate wiring

Tags: walls, socket, speakers

I have standard speaker cables and a wall plate that supports 2 speakers (i.e. 4 wires):

[image: front]

[image: back]

[image: back2]

The front is obvious but I'm confused about the back. Should I pass the wires through the little hole on each contact and leave them hanging? How do I "lock" the wires in place?

Comment: Those connections I believe are made for use with crimp on “female spade lug”. (Google or amazon that term)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I wonder if that's really the way these are supposed to be connected :/

Comment: The hole on your contacts corresponds to a dimple on the female connector that prevents slide off.  I think this is exactly what the maker of your part had in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminals on the back side of that speaker connection adapter are meant to be used with a type of crimp on terminal such as those pictured below:

[image]

<sup>*(Picture source - https://www.arc-components.com/2-001-34-pack-of-100-durite-coloured-crimp-terminal-480mm-push-on-red.html)*</sup>

These come in various sizes, colors and styles. Some types are covered with insulation and others like above are insulated only in the crimp area. The terminal is pushed onto the short stripped end of the in wall wire then crimped in place using a special tool designed for this purpose. The terminal is then pushed onto the flat ends of the terminals on the back side of that mount plate.

You can source these from many places including your local auto parts store.

Comment: Got a confirmation from the re-seller that these indeed are the intended connectors. Weird if you ask me but oh well :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to purchase your  connectors at an audio specific  retailer.  Audio  connectors will be of a higher quality ( gold or silver plated ) because low quality  metal connectors and speaker wires can have a negative effect on the sound quality.

I would probably solder them since they live in the wall and would not need to be disconnected. I found [these](https://www.parts-express.com/gold-18-16-awg-0205-female-disconnect-5-pair--095-804) at parts express, they are for 16 gauge (AWG) wires, the smallest gauge i would use ( i personally use 14 AWG wire )

Be careful you could fall down the  audiophile rabbit hole Which will empty your bank account.